# A WIX Interpreter?

Tags: installation, wix, windows-installer, interpreter, rpm

I have a need to describe deployments/installs, and possibly uninstalls as well - but I don't want to use Windows Installer.  At the same time, I don't want to completely re-invent the wheel.

It occurred to me that I could perhaps use the WIX declarative schema, but create my own "WIX interpreter" that will perform the install / uninstall steps (as described by a target WIX xml document) without using the windows installer.

It would be nice to go a step further, so that I achieve a cross-platform (Linux, MAC) installer-interpreter.  Of course WIX did not have Linux and MAC in mind.  In which case I either add xml namespaces to extend WIX, or use some other industry format (that I am yet unaware of).

But perhaps I'm stretching too far.  At the very least it would be nice to have a WIX interpreter or a WIX install executable that **does not create any records in the windows installer**.  It need not fulfill every capability of the windows installer.  I'd just like to see some basic capabilities fulfilled.

Does anyone know of such a thing, so I can save myself the effort of making it myself?

Comment: When you say a WIX install that does not create records in the windows installer, it implies a partial misunderstanding of how the windows installer works.  WIX creates a MSI, which is a bunch of database records put into a file based database.  Later a component called from MSI exec reads those entries and performs the installation.  A "does not create any records" install would in fact install nothing.  Unless you meant "does not create any registry records".  Even then, msiexec will create a few "record keeping" records of the install in the registry anyway.

Comment: I've removing the installer, wix and msi tags because this doesn't have any thing to do with any of them.  What you are really talking about is writing an application that parses XML documents that just happen to have a schema similar to WiX.

Comment: I reverted to restore the installer and wix tags, since those represeent the primary audience I am addressing: people with that knowledge and know how to apply those technologies.

Answer (score 2):

Each operating system has their own means of managing installed packages.

That means that if you implement your own package management scheme, it will not integrate well with the current operating system standard.  This has a number of very bad side effects, mainly the people maintaining the operating system through standard tools run a high risk of not knowing your software was installed because the standard tool didn't report it was installed.

Microsoft's installer is quite different than many other installers, and it supports extension via programming, which is typically done in the <del>VB</del> C++ language.  Also, Microsoft supports the mixing of configuration and installation, while many other package managers see these as different functions to be performed at different times.  Finally, Microsoft attempts to ask for the configuration information PRIOR to installation, while installers that separate out the role of configuration and installation typically request that the configuration be done AFTER the program is installed.

In truth, there are way too many different "assumptions" about what constitutes installation, and when / how to do said items, and what tools can be expected on particular platforms to easily merge "all items" into a single multiple-system installation tool without the vendors coordinating a little bit to allow for some compatibility.

Comment: Why not just use Wine for your target install platform?

Comment: Edited: *Typically* you extend Windows Installer using native code, e.g. C++ - managed code (C#, VB) or scripting languages (VBScript, JScript) can cause many problems for new setup developers when trying to debug on real-world customer machines.